# jsoup не парсит страницу полностью

Tags: jsoup

Добрый день!

У меня проблема заключается в том, что страница

http://www.bm.ru/ru/ofisy-banka/bankomaty/?mode102=1&region102=77&city102=77000000

Если ее сохранять полностью и парсить:

```
htmlFile = Jsoup.parse(new File("c:/test.html"), "UTF-8");
title = htmlFile.title();
List<Element> elms = htmlFile.select(".atm-table-point");
```

То лист заполнен элементами.
А если делать так, то он пустой:

```
htmlFile = Jsoup.connect("http://www.bm.ru/ru/ofisy-banka/bankomaty/?mode102=1&region102=77&city102=77000000")
.userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36")
.execute().parse();
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: В том что список банкоматов подтягивается javascript-ом, а не отдается сразу в тексте страницы.

Comment: Я уже поняла, что с динамическими страницами проблема у jsoup, воспользовалась уже selenium. Спасибо.